# Creating spatial data on-the-fly for timeline application?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, software-recommendations

Facts:

Data are stored in a MySql db with no spatial data. instead there is a uri of gazetteer service which will return spatial data in json format.

Project:

build a **timeline** **webgis** application (***openlayers*** ??) with these data.

My problem is how to proceed ..

Is there a framework which can produce on the fly GeoJSON data out of the box ?

Comment: PostGIS can ...

Comment: PostGIS can convert GeoJSon to spatial but it can not fetch the JSON data fromn the gazeteer .... :-(

Answer (score 1):

I probably find the answer or at least a point to start from.

There is already work done on serving on the fly a spatial layer through geoJson.
https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON

In my case I will change the code so as get the layer attributes from the db & the location from the external gazetteer & build on the fly a GeoJSON response.